# Problems with vuze plugins

Tags: fedora, software-rec

I needed a torrent client that supports feeds and mailing me when stuff is finished. Vuze supports feeds and a plugin was supposed to do the trick about mailing me.

But I have encountered great difficulties installing the plugin. I've selected it and then the application hangs when it tries to install it through the installation guide. I think I could just copy the files over to the vuze plugins folder and restart vuze.

Would that work? And where does the vuze install the plugins folder when I installed it with `yum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find where `yum` puts your plugin, try searching for it:

```
find / -name [your_plugin's_name] &2> /dev/null
```

Alternatively, I believe Vuze can install plugins from it's configuration menu. You should give that a check as well.

Answer (score -1):

Deluge torrent client can be run as a daemon, can be controlled with it's own GUI or over HTTP. It has a nice feature 'Execute command when torrent is finished' where you can put a simple `sendmail` or `mail` command.